# Yii2 How to handle Swift_TransportException exception?

Tags: exception, yii2, swiftmailer, yii2-advanced-app

When trying to send mail using swiftmailer I am getting the following error:

```
Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 User test@test.com has exceeded its 24-hour sending limit. Messages to 250 recipients out of 250 allowed have been sent. Relay quota will reset in 1.47 hours.
```

I have put the swiftmailer in the try catch block as follows:

```
public function sendMail($emailTemplateName, $subject, $body, $fromEmail, $toEmail)
{
        try
        {
            return Yii::$app->mailer->compose(['html' => $emailTemplateName], ['emailBody' => $body])
                ->setFrom([ $fromEmail => Yii::$app->params['siteTitle'] ])
                ->setTo($toEmail)
                ->setSubject($subject)
                ->send();
        }
        catch(Swift_SwiftException $exception)
        {
            return 'Can sent mail due to the following exception'.print_r($exception);
        }
}
```

I also tried with `Swift_SwiftException` and `Exception` but exeption doesn't get caught.

How can I handle this exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok got it. I needed to use `\Swift_TransportException` in catch.